# read_file didn't work codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, bind

I was doing my project, update the content of named.conf.local in BIND server using webpage which I created using codeigniter. When I running it, File unable to write. Those are my controller code:

```
function index() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('domain_name','Domain Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'Mail', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('localhost', 'Localhost', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('dns_form');
    } else {
        $domain_name = $this->input->post('domain_name');
        $mail = $this->input->post('mail');
        $localhost = $this->input->post('localhost');
        $data = $domain_name . "\n" . $mail . "\n" . $localhost;

        if (!read_file('/etc/bind/named.conf.local' . $domain_name, $data, 'a+')) {
            echo 'Unable to write this file';
        } else {
            echo 'File written!';
        }
    }
```

I've given permission on the server with `chmod -R 777 /etc/bind`. What's wrong with my code? Thanks for help.

Comment: Use to write the file `file_put_contents('/etc/bind/named.conf.local', $data)`

Comment: I've changed it, and running again. But, it said  file_put_contents() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given. what's wrong, sir?

Comment: Are you passing 3rd parameter? because above example contain only 2 parameter check care fully.

Comment: I think this is the wrong part, '/etc/bind/named.conf.local' . $domain_name, $data, 'a+'. I put $domain_name as file name. I've delete that, and changed  'a+' to FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX. What is FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX use for actually? Why does it work using FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX?

Comment: FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX.. This argument will append your content with existing content in your file. if you will not use this one your file will be override every time. `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php`

Comment: Your welcome, i am going to make this one as Answer please make it accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one will work for you->

```
$file ='file_path';
$data = 'Your Data';
file_put_contents($file, $data , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

To note, read_file ('/path/to/file') only accept one parameter. This path file will start to the location of your index.php